# Return new date string in the same format as input

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I've got two columns: varchar column **InputValue** with input dates (all strings pass IsDate(InputValue)=1 validation) and datetime column **NewDate** with new dates. How do I return new dates as a string in the same format as in input dates? Example (I need **OutputValue** to contain **NewDate** value and be formatted the same way as **InputValue**):

```
    InputValue    NewDate       OutputValue
    (varchar)     (datetime)    (varchar)
    20010101      02/02/2002    20020202
    01-01-2000    12/25/2001    12-25-2001
    Aug 12 2012   11/15/2000    Nov 15 2000
```

Is there any way to find out the style of the input date, so I can just use CONVERT(varchar, NewDate, @inputStyle)? Or maybe you have any custom code to get as close to the result as possible?
Thank you!

Comment: If `03/02/2002` passes `ISDATE()` validation, how can you be sure whether the author meant March 2nd or February 3rd? Passing `ISDATE` doesn't mean you're interpreting the intention correctly. (Basically, don't take arbitrary string input from users; have them pick from a control or dropdown, that way _you_ can dictate exactly one input format and not mess with regional shenanigans.)

Comment: The *format* of the data should be determined by the presentation layer, not the SQL layer, and certainly data like a `datetime` should never be stored as a `varchar`. If different users want to be able to consume dates in different formats, empower them to be able to do so with preferences they can set in your application, but *store* and handle the data as a strongly typed date and time data type.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : I'm assuming input is made by US users so month always goes before day.

Comment: But why leave it up to your assumptions? Why not protect yourself from a future intern from _literally any other country_?

Comment: All: I'm not taking anything from users, I already have dates in varchar, changing the db struct is out of scope. I just need to update dates in existing varchar columns, but want to keep the format as close to the original as possible. Shenanigans is a good word for what I'm trying to do haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TRY_CONVERT` to attempt a conversion using a variety of styles, then convert the value back and compare it to see if the style matches. See also [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles).

```sql
DECLARE @T TABLE (InputValue varchar(30), NewDate date, ExpectedValue varchar(30));

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('20010101', '02/02/2002', '20020202'),
('01-01-2000', '12/25/2001', '12-25-2001'),
('Aug 12 2012', '11/15/2000', 'Nov 15 2000');

SELECT *,
  OutputValue = (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      OutputValue = CONVERT(varchar(30), t.NewDate, v.style)
    FROM (VALUES
        (0),(110),(112)
    ) v(style)
    WHERE t.InputValue = CONVERT(varchar(30), TRY_CONVERT(date, t.InputValue, v.style), v.style)
  )
FROM @T t;
```

I've only added three styles. You can add all of them if you think they may be relevant

```
    FROM (VALUES
        (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(24),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(20),(21),(22),(100),(101),(102),(103),(104),(105),(106),(107),(108),(9),(110),(111),(112),(113),(114),(120),(25),(121),(23),(126),(127),(130),(131)
    ) v(style)
```

> It goes without saying that this type of table design is really bad.

Comment: Awesome! Not sure which one would run faster, but really works!) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be quite an undertaking to write rules for all possible date formats, but if you just wanted those and for reasons that are your own entirely, it could be done with iif functions:

```
  DECLARE @T TABLE (InputValue varchar(20), NewDate date, OutputValue varchar(20))
  
  INSERT INTO @T SELECT '20010101', '02/02/2002', '20020202'
  INSERT INTO @T SELECT '01-01-2000', '12/25/2001', '12-25-2001'
  INSERT INTO @T SELECT 'Aug 12 2012', '11/15/2000', 'Nov 15 2000'

  select    InputValue
          , NewDate
          , OutputValue
          , iif(len(InputValue) = 8, convert(varchar(20), NewDate, 112)
            , iif(InputValue LIKE '[A-Za-z]%', convert(varchar(20), NewDate, 107)
                , convert(varchar(20), NewDate, 32))) derived
  from @t
```

Comment: Haha, looks like a perfect working solution! I'll take this answer and extend to other styles if there's no more straightforward way to determine format.