# Convert multiple different date formats in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an example table with different date formats like this:

```
 | date-column | 
 ------------
 | 20150812    |
 | 03/07/2013  | 
 | 2017-09-23  | 
 |  --Etc--    |
```

How can I change or convert all the date formats? For example I want to change all the dates into format `yyyymmdd` and I tried doing so using

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, date-column, 112)
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to sort out your data source first. Are the different date formats known and limited/fixed.

Comment: @Shmiel it's a string Varchar data type

Comment: is `03/07/2013` 3rd of July or 7th of March?

Comment: Possibly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490178/14868997

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```sql
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast(date-column as date), 112)
```

Just take care of the format of your dates if it's `dmy` or `mdy`, it should be consistent.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f058c32eaec34529cc703c2b14325f01)

Answer (score 1):

This could help you:

```sql
update dates
set date-column = cast(date-column as date)
```

> I guess the 'date-column' have type varchar or similar.