# Convert mixed format string datetime value to datetime datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

SQL Server 2019 is receiving data from upstream PostgreSQL.

The four date columns are defined as datatype `Varchar(50)` and hold datetime values like this:

```
2021-12-09 09:16:09+00
2021-12-15T02:40:39+01:00
2021-12-15 1:27:56
2021-12-15 0:45:00
```

How can I convert this from `varchar` to proper `datetime` datatype and insert to another table in SQL Server 2019?

Comment: I suggest fixing your data at its source and getting it into a single common format.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Thanks, but Upstream source is out of scope for us. We are authorised only to modify downstream data.

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490178/14868997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* try using the base string functions along with `TRY_CONVERT()` here:

```sql
SELECT dt,
       TRY_CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(dt, 1, 10) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(dt, 12, 8)) AS dt_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Here is a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4696e8735403eca067fcb632dea5777b).