# when try to convert varchar data type (mixed date formats) to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server, datetime, varchar, sqldatatypes

These are some values stored in my `started_at` column:

```
31/5/2022 10:27 
1/5/2022 17:03
24/6/2022 9:54 
.
.
.
2022-08-09 19:09:55 
2022-08-18 14:58:56
2022-11-17 22:50:52
```

There are more than 1'000'000 rows and have mixed date formats like these 2.

So when I execute this SQL to try and convert to `datetime` datatype:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(started_at AS DATETIME), 103) 
FROM 
    [dbo].[testCyclistic12m]
```

I get this error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 39
> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I don't know why....

Can anyone help me? I'd appreciate it very much

Comment: This is not MySQL, it's MS SQL Server.

Comment: 1. Please know which product you're using and tag correctly, 2. don't store dates as strings and definitely don't store mixed formats and ambiguous formats.

Comment: Style `103` for the value `'2022-08-09 19:09:55'` is going to mean the 2022nd *day* of the 8th month, of the "9th" (2009? 1909?) year. Hopefully you can see why that's a problem.

Comment: you can do COALESCE together with TRY_CONVERT and test different styles until you get something that looks like date. Another crazy idea would be to fix your data so you don't store different values, but it might be too much to ask

Comment: This is a problem for your ETL/ELT layer, not really for SQL Server. You'd be much better off sanitizing before the data winds up in your RDMS.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```sql
SELECT  COALESCE(try_convert(datetime, col1, 103), try_convert(datetime, col1, 121 )) AS converted_col1
,   col1
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'31/5/2022 10:27 ')
    ,   (N'1/5/2022 17:03')
    ,   (N'24/6/2022 9:54 ')
    ,   (N'2022-08-09 19:09:55 ')
    ,   (N'2022-08-18 14:58:56')
    ,   (N'2022-11-17 22:50:52')
) t (col1)
```

It tries to cast to dd/mm/yyyy style first, and the regular yyyy-mm-dd in the second.

Output:

| converted_col1 | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-31 10:27:00.000 | 31/5/2022 10:27 |
| 2022-05-01 17:03:00.000 | 1/5/2022 17:03 |
| 2022-06-24 09:54:00.000 | 24/6/2022 9:54 |
| 2022-09-08 19:09:55.000 | 2022-08-09 19:09:55 |
| 2022-08-18 14:58:56.000 | 2022-08-18 14:58:56 |
| 2022-11-17 22:50:52.000 | 2022-11-17 22:50:52 |

Comment: I have tried from beginning again before I combine all tables into one that results mix dates like that,so I go through 1 by 1 table to change the datetime and then combine it again.now I got all uniform dates...still I will try this way to ..thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You have an extraordinarily difficult problem to solve in a robust way. You want "garbage in, good data out".

`CAST(started_at AS DATETIME)` is unsuitable for this problem because it  doesn't ingest all imaginable date / time text formats. You need somehow to detect which date format is present in each row and use the appropriate [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles) value in `CONVERT(DATETIIME, started_at, style)`.

Without knowing how many different text formats are in your table, it's difficult to give you more specific advice.

Comment: Here's a horrible but very cool solution to try every possible style for a match https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490178/14868997